# how to Implemented zoom out in my automation test?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, webdriver-io

i wanna ask. i got problem when i implemented the zoom out in my testing code. the example code like this

```
describe('demoqa web testing', () => {
    beforeEach(async function(){
        await browser.maximizeWindow();
    });

    it('form testing', async() => {
        await browser.url("https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form");
        await browser.execute(() => {
           return document.body.style.zoom = '50%';
        });
    })
})
```

I'm using webdriverIO and the problem is, when i run npx wdio. the browser can't be zoom out until 50%. maybe do you have some advice on my code? thank you

so, i'm expecting when i run the test, and then the browser already zoom out

Comment: `zoom` is not a standard CSS property. [Avoid using it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom#browser_compatibility).